# when the andi mips instruction can be illegal

Tags: assembly, mips, instructions

The format for the mips instruction `andi $a0, $a0, 0x9AE3` looks correct. It's an I type format *opcode rs rt immediate*. Why is an invalid mips instruction?

Comment: It *is* valid and legal.  `clang -target mips -c foo.s` assembles it just fine; I checked in case there was something I was missing.  The constant is representable by the 16-bit zero-extended immediate (unlike in RISC-V), and those are legal MIPS registers.  If you have some reason to think it isn't, include details (a [mcve]).  Did you try to assemble it in MIPS16 mode (compressed instructions)?

Comment: I was reading a paper and that's the only information. Then it asks why is not a valid MIPS instruction? I'm not an expert but as I said, it looks correct.

Comment: What paper?  Does it have a URL?  The fact that an assembler assembles it to a single machine instruction for real MIPS makes the question problematic (based on a false premise.) Something future readers can check themselves.  But asking about an error in a specific book or paper can be relevant.  (Or perhaps they were talking about a modified MIPS that works differently, not a real MIPS.  Lots of student projects and stuff use simplified MIPS with variations on compatibility with the real commercial MIPS ISA, so that's another reason to be specific about what MIPS.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Peter says, if the constant is too large to fit in the immediate field, the assembler will either reject that line or translate that into multiple instructions that build some of the constant within the process of doing the operation requested.

However, *for `andi` the immediate field is 16 bits that are treated as **unsigned***, which means we get a range of 0x0000-0xFFFF, and 0x9000 is clearly within that range.

Now, if the opcode was `addi`, the difference is that *for `addi` the same 16-bit immediate field is treated as **signed***, which means we get the range 0xFFFF8000-0x00007FFF, and here 0x9000 is out of that range (so the assembler will either reject that line of assembly code, or substitute with a 2 (or more) instruction sequence, since it cannot be encoded in one instruction).

---

As a side note, many MIPS assemblers are super friendly, and will take "sensible" instructions and operands that the processor doesn't naturally support and treat them as pseudo instructions that are instead implemented by a sequence of multiple machine code instructions.  This is so prevalent in the MIPS mind set as can be evidenced by the reservation of an entire CPU register (`$at`/`$1`) as temporary storage for such expansions.  In RISC V this has gone away, and only pseudo instructions that can reuse the target are allowed and otherwise the (human) assembly programmer has to write an appropriate code sequence (and that might involve identifying a free register).  IMHO, this is a good thing, b/c the MIPS assemblers hide things that shouldn't be hidden in assembly — for example, translating some innocent looking instructions into a 3-instruction sequence, and when these occur inside a loop, with some thought, much better could have been done (if the assembly programmer had not had that "assistance" by the assembler and was alerted to consider the situation in terms of what the hardware can more directly).

---

Let's also note that in RISC V all immediates are sign extended, so they've also removed the different handling of immediate for `andi` vs. `addi`.  As @Peter also notes, the RISC V immediates are smaller as well, and both of these increase the workload of programmers and compilers, but make the hardware more efficient by only needing one hardware mechanism for enlarging immediates (i.e. sign extension and no zero extension), and by   making better use of encoding bits (more bits for opcodes, for greater instruction set longevity and custom instruction set expansion).

Comment: Oh, right, RISC-V I-type instructions have a narrower immediate, too.  So that's another way that it would be ruled out there.  I wondered if the OP maybe had some kind of simplified homebrew MIPS that sign-extended all its immediates like RISC-V does.  Or at least changed `andi`, if not `ori` / `xori`, since `p & -16` or whatever is handy for alignment, but MIPS can't do it in one instruction.